# I have to measure the maximum height but error in one button,

Tags: java, android

I'm in the last grade of high school and they let me as a project to measure the maximum height of a parabolic shot. I already have the program and it works fine but the error happens when I don't put information in the PlainText and the program closes (Android Studio). I saw that I could do something with the button "FloatingActionButton", but I do not know how to place that in my java code.

Here is my Java code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText velocityEditText;
    private EditText angleEditText;
    private Button calculateButton;
    private TextView resultTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        velocityEditText = findViewById(R.id.velocity_edit_text);
        angleEditText = findViewById(R.id.angle_edit_text);
       calculateButton=findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        resultTextView = findViewById(R.id.result_text_view);

        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    double velocity = Double.parseDouble(velocityEditText.getText().toString());
                    double angle = Double.parseDouble(angleEditText.getText().toString());
                    double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
                    double range = ((Math.pow(velocity, 2)) * (Math.pow(Math.sin(radians), 2))) / (2 * 9.81);
                    resultTextView.setText("Altura Máxima: " + String.format("%.2f", range) + " m");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EFECAF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="Velocidad inicial (m/s):"
        android:textColor="#100F0F" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/velocity_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="#0E0E0E" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="Ángulo de lanzamiento (grados):"
        android:textColor="#121111" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/angle_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="#0E0E0E" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF9800"
        android:text="Calcular altura máxima" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#100F0F"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/altura" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm sorry if I didn't put the code information correctly, but this is the first time I'm asking a question here.

If I leave the text fields empty and click the button, then the app is crashing.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language you have used for coding is Java and not Javascript(JS). The application is crashing, because if no text is entered, then, the `Double.parseDouble()` function is used on an empty string. To solve that, replace your `calculateButton.setOnClickListener()` with this:

```
calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //Check if text fields are empty
            if (!velocityEditText.getText().toString().equals("") && !angleEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    double velocity = Double.parseDouble(velocityEditText.getText().toString());
                    double angle = Double.parseDouble(angleEditText.getText().toString());
                    double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
                    double range = ((Math.pow(velocity, 2)) * (Math.pow(Math.sin(radians), 2))) / (2 * 9.81);
                    resultTextView.setText("Altura Máxima: " + String.format("%.2f", range) + " m");
            }
            else{
             //Show message to user if no text is entered
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in the text fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    });
```

In the above code, we first check if the strings are not empty and then we pass the strings to the `Double.parseDouble()` function. If the text fields are empty, then, we show a message to the user.